# How to trigger events from within a custom html element class

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have a custom HTMLElement called `<test-tag>`. My goal now is to call a DOM event from that element‘s class constructor, so that when a element like `<test-tag onclick= ‘alert(“constructed“);‘>` is added to the DOM, the constructor triggers that onclick event and “constructed“ gets alerted.

Here is what I have tried yet but it is not working:
https://jsfiddle.net/mnat6qxb/15/

HTML:

```
<test-tag onclick="alert('test')">Test</test-tag>
```

JavaScript:

```
class TestTag extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));    
  }
}

customElements.define('test-tag', TestTag, { extends: 'p' });
```

Comment: You don't do DOM stuff in the ``constructor``; as it will also run on ``document.createElement("test-tag")`` The ``connectedCallback`` fires when an element is added to the DOM. Also note ``extends:"p"`` does not and will never work in Apples Safari browser.